# Why does below regex not work in vim? (Specifically, the ? in the regex)

Tags: regex, vim

```
[0-9]* (-)?[0-9]* q
```

This regex does not seem to work in vim for below text

> 34778965 -1 q some text here

[SOLVED]

Thank you! I realize it all has to be escaped. What felt inconsistent is some needed to be escaped like \? but some not, like * or $. vimregex.com helped.

Comment: Did you check http://vimregex.com/?

Comment: You could use `\d` for digits. `\d\+ -\? \d\-` should work.

Comment: I've never used Vim but from what I see on Federico's link, you need to escape the parenthesis for groups to work. Try with `[0-9]* \(-\)?[0-9]* q`
You might also have to escape the `-`, not sure about this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\d` to denote numbers in vim regex.

A good pattern for your text would be

```
       \d\+ -\? \d\+ q
```

In general, vim assumes that the characters as their literal ones. So, if you give `\d+`, it would be understood as any digit follows by a plus sign. So, you will have to escape such regex specific characters in patterns.

Answer (score 2):

In Vim, you need to escape some common regex special characters for them to act as special operators. E.g. `(-)` group must be written in a non very magic mode as `\(-\)`. In a very magic mode, your pattern would work as is - `:%s/\v[0-9]* (-)?[0-9]* q/replace/g`

In your case, you just do not need the grouping at all because you quantify one single hyphen inside parentheses, so they can be removed:

```
[0-9]* -\? [0-9]* q
```